# What software is used to produce this videos?

Tags: software, animation

I am wondering what software is used to produce video like this ? note it contains animation , sound effects, graphics, etc.

Best reagrds

Comment: You can use Adobe After effects for this kind of videos.

Comment: An animation like this could be produced on a large range of software. You'd need an image editor - eg gimp, photoshop. Then you need a program that can do animation, eg. blender, natron, synapse, after effects, nuke. You'll need something to record and edit audio, eg. audacity, protools, adobe audition, lmms, and probably a NLE to cut it all together, eg Kino, kdenlive, blender, final cut, imovie, premiere, windows movie maker. 
Thing is that the software does do the animation, the animator does.

Comment: Thanks @stib , I am looking for one software that can be do the whole job. by the way there is some online services make perfect animation like that like goanimate.com, but what I need is one program.

Comment: I'm building a house. Can you recommend a tool that will do the whole job for me?

Comment: @stib OK ,, Idea have revealed clearly .. TNX